# Excel to find three characters left of a field that varies

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2013, vba

For my work I've created a VBA code to add new accounts from a report that shows purchases for the month to a master sheet with all accounts and inventories. I need to extract the region from a purchase order number but it varies depending on the type of purchase.

The region will always be the first three characters to the left of the 6 digits: **ABC**123456A. In this case I need to extract the letters ABC.

But it changes depending on the type of order. Some orders will add a sub-territory to the front order number and an underscore, such as XYZABC_**ABC**123456A.

If the order was for a new account the last letter on the right will be an A, if the order was for consignment it will be a C, but if it was for orthotics and prosthetics it will change to OP: **ABC**123456OP

I need a formula to help me specifically extract that three letter territory that comes before 6 digits when the number of characters may vary. Please help.

Comment: `=IFERROR(MID(A1,FIND("_",A1)+1,3),LEFT(A1,3))`???

Comment: If Dirk's formula doesn't work, then you have not provided enough examples to show the variability possible in your PO numbers.

Comment: Is it a formula in a cell on a worksheet you need or is it VBA code you need? Your question and tags are conflicting.

Answer (score 1):

If you did want a vba solution, you can use the split function to store the parts of the code then extract the first three letters of the last array entry...

```
Dim Code As String: Code = "XYZABC_ABC123456A"
Dim Arr() As String: Arr = Split(Code, "_")
MsgBox Left(Arr(UBound(Arr)), 3)
```

Comment: still: `Public Function GetCode(Code As String) As String: GetCode = Mid(Code, InStr(Code, "_") + 1, 3): End Function` would be faster :P

Comment: Yes - but assuming there will only be one sub-territory or less. In the case of multiple underscores being present [it's not really mentioned that there will only ever be one or less] then the code above should still return the correct string

Comment: Yes and no... it is not said how multiple underscores need to be treated... if looking just for the first one yours will fail... but asuming there will never be more than one, all codes should do fine...

Comment: And for going for the last underscore you could use `Public Function GetCode(Code As String) As String: GetCode = Mid(Code, InStrRev(Code, "_") + 1, 3): End Function`... will also be faster :P